# Eclipse plug-in to write xml configuration file for hibrnate and spring

Tags: xml, spring, eclipse

I am a hibernate and spring learner. Writing xml files (weather its for hibernate or for spring) its really very hard to remember each and every property which leads to sometime compilation/runtime error.

Is there any plug-in for eclispe which provide intelligence for xml editor to view the properties so that we can set them in xml file.